# Parse data with no content with Gson

Tags: java, json, gson, android

I am receiving from a server the following data:

```
data":[[ "15", "", 0, 254, 0, "0m", "N", 0, 1, "N", 0 ], [ "3", "Other", 504, 2, 36, "503m", "NW", 310, 1, "SE", 130 ] ],
```

I understand the inside is an array of an object, but I dont get to parse the whole information using Gson because I cannot parse the data inside as there is no title names. How can I do it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I'd just point out that the data you have posted is not valid JSON.

Answer (score -1):

Start with root array element and iterate over each element:
you can check value type with instanceof Integer for example.
and do element.getAsInt().

For more details on JsonElement please read:

https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html

Comment: Thanks, but what I need is to know whether it is possible using Gson or not. I know how to do it manually, but I would like to do it automatically using Gson